# Connecting a Mac to the office network

Tags: macos, windows-vista, networking, network-shares

I am busy preparing to start working with a Mac at work - in addition to my old PC.

Just wondered, is it difficult to setup the Mac to run on the office network - i.e. does it need any special settings or servers or anything like that?  and also printers...can I use the network printer as normal.

I am just pottrying to think ahead of any ential issues.

Also share drives...will I be able to access share drives and my backups to these shares drives - all a bit daunting!

Btw in case you didn't notice I am a Mac Nube lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy. There are are too many variables to be specific. For example, is your work network all Microsoft? What vintage? What kind of security?

The basic protocols are all built in in the Mac. You can share disc with [SMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block), [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), FTP, etc.

The printers are easy. Most printers have an built-in driver in OS X. First try to connect using Bonjour (apple's zero config networking client) and then use either Windows (SMB) or IP protocols. Try to use the native OS X drivers before installing the manufacturers drivers. There are a surprising large number of printer drivers built in in OS X.

The best way to get along / go along is to fit in with what is there. Find a friendly Mac sympathetic propeller head or IT guy to help you.